# What is the terminal command to stop a running snap package program?

Tags: snap

I have a snap package program running, but it refuses to stop, it still has its icon in the tray area, but no matter what I do it will not end.  That made me think of these questions:

1. Is there a terminal command to see the current status (running, not running, etc.) of a snap package?
2. Is there a a terminal command to end a snap package, similar to the kill command?

Comment: I've always just used `kill` (`killall` etc) or `htop` treating it like any other process (be it `chromium` or any other snap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A running snap is a process like any other. 1) The snap will appear among the other running processes in the output of `top`, `htop`, `System monitor`, etc. 2) You therefore can also use the `kill` command or one of the tools mentioned to stop the snap like you can for other processes.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to vanadium's answer, snap has some [additional management options](https://snapcraft.io/docs/service-management) (this may or may not be useful for your particular scenario, but for completeness sake I think it is worth mentioning).

Use `snap services` to lists all the services added to the system by the currently installed and enabled snaps.

```
Service                                   Startup  Current   Notes
canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd  enabled  active    -
lxd.activate                              enabled  inactive  -
lxd.daemon                                enabled  inactive  socket-activated
```

The `start` and `stop` commands control whether a service should be currently running:

```
$ sudo snap stop lxd.daemon
Stopped.

$ sudo snap start lxd.daemon
Started.
```

Finally, if a snap has undesired behaviour, you can `disable` it and later `enable` it again. This avoids having to remove and reinstall them in the system:

```
$ sudo snap disable vlc
vlc disabled

$ sudo snap enable vlc
vlc enabled
```